# Mod Making, crash on drawing things to the screen?

Tags: java, crash, minecraft

I'm making a hacked client/cheats for a game called Minecraft. I compiled my mods, and when I try to turn something on, I get a crash report on wherever it is drawing the hack name to the screen.

I can't tell what is wrong, it works perfectly in Eclipse but not in the game. Anything clearly wrong with this code?

```
if(Client.flight){
            var8.drawString("Flight",GuiScreen.width-var8.getStringWidth("Flight")-1,arraySeperator,0xCCFF33);
            arraySeperator+=11;
        }
        if(Client.sneak){
            var8.drawString("Sneak",GuiScreen.width-var8.getStringWidth("Sneak")-1,arraySeperator,0x007700);
            arraySeperator+=11;
        }
        if(Client.nofall){
            var8.drawString("NoFall",GuiScreen.width-var8.getStringWidth("NoFall")-1,arraySeperator,0xFF0000);
            arraySeperator+=11;
        }
        if(Client.sprint){
            var8.drawString("Speed",GuiScreen.width-var8.getStringWidth("Speed")-1,arraySeperator,0x99CCFF);
            arraySeperator+=11;
        }
        if(Client.killaura){
            var8.drawString("Kill Aura",GuiScreen.width-var8.getStringWidth("Kill Aura")-1,arraySeperator,0xe11a1a);
            arraySeperator+=11;
        }
        if(Client.brightness){
            var8.drawString("Brightness",GuiScreen.width-var8.getStringWidth("Brightness")-1,arraySeperator,0xCCFF33);
            mc.gameSettings.gammaSetting = 10000;
            arraySeperator+=11;
        }else{
            mc.gameSettings.gammaSetting = 1;
        }
        if(Client.speedmine){
            var8.drawString("Cleany Consuela",GuiScreen.width-var8.getStringWidth("Cleany Consuela")-1,arraySeperator,0xF4DF76);
            arraySeperator+=11;
        }
        if(Client.instant){
            var8.drawString("Instant",GuiScreen.width-var8.getStringWidth("Instant")-1,arraySeperator,0xf4df76);
            arraySeperator+=11;
        }
        if(Client.tracers){
            var8.drawString("Tracers",GuiScreen.width-var8.getStringWidth("Tracers")-1,arraySeperator,0xFF0000);
            arraySeperator+=11;
        }
```

It's in the right place; everything is perfect. When I try turning something on it crashes on the var8.drawString lines.

Here's the stacktrace/crash report:

```
ava.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expected static field awe.g
at avj.a(GuiIngame.java:370)
at bfe.b(SourceFile:700)
at atv.S(SourceFile:686)
at atv.d(SourceFile:619)
at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:101)
```

A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:

---

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at avj.a(GuiIngame.java:370)

-- Affected level --
Details:
    Level name: MpServer
    All players: 1 total; [bdi['ostrichparty101'/11, l='MpServer', x=-757.69, y=4.62, z=1605.43]]
    Chunk stats: MultiplayerChunkCache: 441
    Level seed: 0
    Level generator: ID 01 - flat, ver 0. Features enabled: false
    Level generator options: 
    Level spawn location: World: (-744,4,1570), Chunk: (at 8,0,2 in -47,98; contains blocks -752,0,1568 to -737,255,1583), Region: (-2,3; contains chunks -64,96 to -33,127, blocks -1024,0,1536 to -513,255,2047)
    Level time: 799 game time, 799 day time
    Level dimension: 0
    Level storage version: 0x00000 - Unknown?
    Level weather: Rain time: 0 (now: false), thunder time: 0 (now: false)
    Level game mode: Game mode: creative (ID 1). Hardcore: false. Cheats: false
    Forced entities: 1 total; [bdi['ostrichparty101'/11, l='MpServer', x=-757.69, y=4.62, z=1605.43]]
    Retry entities: 0 total; []
    Server brand: vanilla
    Server type: Integrated singleplayer server
Stacktrace:
    at bdd.a(SourceFile:284)
    at atv.b(SourceFile:1761)
    at atv.d(SourceFile:633)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:101)

Comment: You really started your question off with *I'm making a hacked client/cheats for a game called Minecraft* and expect us to help?  If only there was a Speedyclose button

Answer (score 0):

The changes you have made to the client code have made it incompatible with the Minecraft runtime library. Since it works in Eclipse, the IDE must be using a different version of the library. Recompile the library and any of its dependencies and deploy them to your runtime environment.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm doing this the exact way I've done in the past; many times. Additionally, all of the code here is built into Minecraft.

Comment: Going off the error which says that you have a mismatch between the calling code and one of the Minescraft JAR files. What do you mean built-in. Jars with no source? If so you might be stuck as that Jar file appears to be obfuscated

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a ScaledResolution object, not referencing the GuiScreen.width directly.

```
new ScaledResolution(Minecraft.getMinecraft().gameSettings, Minecraft.getMinecraft().displayWidth, Minecraft.getMinecraft().displayHeight);
```

Then you can use `scaledResolution.getScaledWidth()` instead of `GuiScreen.width`.

Edit: Just to explain what your error means, you are trying to reference a non-static field GuiScreen.width in a static way. If you want to stick with the GuiScreen width field you'll need to have an instance of some GuiScreen compatible object. Minecraft.getMinecraft().currentScreen references the currently open GuiScreen object, although this reference is null when no Guis are open.